# Opening JSON files with MongoDB on Windows

Tags: json, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data which includes products for a store that is presumably from a MongoDB. When I received the data, it was all in JSON format. What would be the easiest way to explore this data on Windows? I have installed MongoDB, but I can't figure out how to explore it

Comment: Please post a sample product document of the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to explore this data, use the import functionality from the MongoDB shell or MongoDB Compass (awesome tool btw).

MongoDB Import: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#simple-import;
MongoDB Compass: https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass

[image: MongoDB Compass]

Or use the MongoDB shell to explore this data
[image: MongoDB shell]